# Wordcloud use phrases rather than single words

Tags: python, cloud, visualization, cpu-word

I am generating a wordcloud image for single word and that works out fine. I want to generate the image for phrases. [Their documentation states in the very first question](https://www.wordclouds.com/faq/) that for 2 word phrases I need to use `~` to link them. I've tried this method linking my n lenght phrases but it still takes only 2 words in to consideration.

Is this the limit or there is a way to generate wordcloud with more than 2 word phrases?

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(
    width=1000,
    height=1000,
    background_color='black',
    stopwords=STOPWORDS).generate(str(text))
fig = plt.figure(
    figsize=(10, 10),
    facecolor='k',
    edgecolor='k')
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: i'd be surprised if this was built in to the module. Identifying all x-length phrases is going to get very computationally intensive very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have more to do with fitting the phrases into the cloud... if you play with  https://www.wordclouds.com/ you can see that if a term is long AND frequent, the algorithm will have trouble to add into the cloud.

If you put a large concatenated word in the page, you may see this message in the corner:

[image]

with the following message:

> The following words were not drawn:
>
> very long phrase hard (13)
>
> In order to make these words appear in your
> cloud, either shrink the word cloud, or lower the frequency of these
> words in the word list.

The same goes for doing it programaticaly.